# Windows XP Theme Manager and Tnt Unicode in Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, user-interface, unicode, themes, delphi-6

I am using Windows XP Theme Manager in order to have 6.0 controls look-and-feel in my Delphi 6 application (manifest is provided). I have problem with some Tnt Unicode controls, for example with `TTntBitBtn`. As you can see from the image below, all `WideString` captions are treated as regular strings (left: `TTntButton`, right: `TTntBitBtn`):

[image]

Is there a way to make Windows XP Theme Manager treat Tnt Unicode components correctly (or *vice versa*)?

Comment: Are you tried using the TTntThemeManager class defined in the `TntThemeMgr` unit?

Comment: There is no such unit, at least not in the free version (2.3.0).

Comment: It's available in 2.2.3. I don't know why it would have been removed. Maybe it interfered with Delphi 7, which included theme support natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `TTntThemeManager`, which is needed to correctly display themed components, is missing from the last free version of Tnt Unicode controls (2.3.0). The version which contains `TTntThemeManager` (2.2.3) is still available on [Delphi Inspiration Tnt Unicode Controls page](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tntunicodecontrols/index). This is how I merged `TTntThemeManager` to the latest version and make all components display correctly.

Here's the procedure:

1. Download the [ZIP file with TntUnicodeControls 2.2.3](http://web.archive.org/web/20060220062917/http://download.tntware.com/delphi_unicode_controls/TntUnicodeControls.zip).
2. Copy files `TntThemeMgr.pas` and `TntThemeMgrDB.pas` to the folder where Tnt Unicode controls are installed (usually `$(ProgramFiles)\TntWare\Delphi Unicode Controls\Source`).
3. Copy resource files `TntThemeMgr.dcr` and `TntThemeMgrDB.dcr` to the folder with other resource files (usually `$(ProgramFiles)\TntWare\Delphi Unicode Controls\Design`).
4. Copy files `TntThemeManager6.cfg`, `TntThemeManager6.dof`, `TntThemeManager6.dpk` and `TntThemeManager6.res` to the folder with remaining two packages (usually `$(ProgramFiles)\TntWare\Delphi Unicode Controls\Delphi\d6` for Delphi 6).
5. In the file `TntThemeManager6.dpk` correct two paths to resource files: `{$R '..\..\Design\TntThemeMgr.dcr'}` and `{$R '..\..\Design\TntThemeMgrDB.dcr'}`.
6. In the same file correct two paths to source files: `TntThemeMgr in '..\..\Design\TntThemeMgr.pas'` and `TntThemeMgrDB in '..\..\Design\TntThemeMgrDB.pas'`.
7. Finally, in the same file change the first requirement from `ThemeManager6` to `ThemeManagerD6`.
8. Open the `TntThemeManager6.dpk` package file from Delphi and compile it.

If you did everything right the two new components - `TntThemeManager` and `TntThemeManagerDB` will be added to the `TntAdditional` palette in Delphi. Add `TntThemeManager` to your form and, if you provided the manifest file, you will get the correct result:

[image: Correctly displayed TTntbutton and TTntBitBtn]